# jQuery Mobile Collapsible ListView Changing Icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I change the collapsed and expanded icons for the jQuery Mobile ListView? Like the following:

[image]

The following icons are available in jQuery Mobile but they are facing left or right and not up and down. I was wondering if these exists or do I have to use photoshop to include these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The up and down arrows (carat-u and carat-d respectively) should be available in jQuery Mobile http://api.jquerymobile.com/icons/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Problem solved. I need a carat-d and carat-u. I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Great! Yea i was going to mention that is for 1.4, in 1.3 i believe they use arrow-u and arrow-d http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/listview/